# What is the reference in the scene where the husband jokes about naming children?

Tags: danna-wakaranai-ken

In episode 10, when the couple is discussing children's names, the husband makes a reference by saying *"If it's a boy, then Shinji. A girl, then Rei"* （男なら「シンジ」、女なら「レイ」）.

[image]

What is the reference being made in this scene?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [pose](https://www.google.com/search?q=gendo%20ikari%20pose&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=1085&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=KN6BVM98xPNS5ZeB4A8&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ) is typical for [Gendo Ikari](http://myanimelist.net/character/1257/Gendou_Ikari) from the Evangelion series. It even has a page on [knowyourmeme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/the-gendo-pose) and is also featured as an example for 'Finger Tenting' on [tvtropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FingerTenting?from=Main.ClaspYourHandsIfYouDeceive).

[image: Gendo Ikari]

In the series he has a son named Shinji and daughter (sort of) named Rei.
(The reference right afterwards is also to Evangelion's [Kaworu](http://myanimelist.net/character/1261/Kaworu_Nagisa))

Comment: Gendo's pregnant wife Yui says that exact line in a flashback scene.

Comment: @SystemDown - late comment, but I'm watching episode 20 of EVA, where this comes up, and the line is said by Gendo, rather than Yui, who simply asks him if he's made any decisions about names.

Comment: @Maroon - Yeah I remembered the scene, but didn't remember the details all that well. Thanks for the correction!